# Derivative $o(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm not sure what I'm writing about, please correct me if I'm wrong.
These are my hypothesis:

\begin{align*}
\cos(x)&=1+o(x) ~~ x \to 0 \\
\cos'(x)&=-\sin(x) \\
\cos''(x)&=-\cos(x)
\end{align*}

If I take the derivative of $1+o(x)$, the result should be an approximation of $-\sin(0)$, right?
If I consider $[1+o(x)]'$ equals to $o(x)$ or $o(1)$ it doesn't make any difference beacuse $\sin(0)=0=o(1)=o(x)$.

If I reiterate the same process to get the second derivative, the problem gets more interesting.
The second derivative of $1+o(x)$ should be an approximation of $-\cos(0)$.
If I consider

\begin{align*}
o'(x)=o(x) &\implies \cos'(0)=[1+o(x)]'=o(x)=-\sin(0) \\
&\implies \cos''(0)=[cos'(0)]'=o'(x)=o(x)=-\cos(0) \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow \\
\end{align*}

So my guess is that $o'(x)=o(1)$

\begin{align*}
o'(x)=o(1) &\implies \cos'(0)=[1+o(x)]'=o(1)=-\sin(0) \\
&\implies \cos''(0)=[cos'(0)]'=o'(1)=[everything]=-\cos(0) 
\end{align*}

P.S:

\begin{align*}
o'(f(x))&=\{g'(x)|g(x)=o(f(x))\} \\
o(1)&=\{f(x)|\lim_{x \to x_{0}} f(x) = 0\}
\end{align*}
These two equations implies that $o'(1)=[everything]$.

I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: $o(x)$ property is somewhat global, and derivative is about local property.

Comment: I understand that is not a good idea but I would like to educate my intuition

Comment: consider like $e^x+x\sinx=e^x+O(x)$

Comment: could you please read the edited version? I'm sorry for the old one

Comment: But what is your question ??

Comment: My interpretation of o'(x) to make sense of the statements above

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(x)=o(1)$ is true, just like $x=o(1)$.

(For $x\to0$, of course.)

---

Though I am not sure, your question seems related to

$$f(x)=o(g(x))\implies f'(x)=o'(g(x)).$$

Using your definition,

$$f(x)=o(g(x))\implies f'(x)\in\{h'(x)|h(x)=o(g(x))\}$$ is a tautology.

If on another hand, your question is about

$$o'(g(x))=o(g'(x)),$$

this is clearly wrong in the general case.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the quest in the wrong way. I would like to lead to a contradiction if $o'(x)=o(x)$

Comment: You should define the notation $o'(x)$. And you should update your question.

Comment: I edited the post. I wrote the definition on the P.S. section

Comment: @DavideModesto: your definition of $o(1)$ does not make sense. $o(1)$ has nothing to do with $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I edited, is it right now? I really appraciate your answer. I was more interested in showing that $o'(x)\neq o(x) $ and I think you confirmed that is not like so

Comment: @DavideModesto: I did not address this particular question.

Comment: Isn't it like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109140/discussion-between-davide-modesto-and-yves-daoust).

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't differentiate little $o$s. Consider, for instance, $$x^2\sin\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)=o(x)$$ and its derivative. However, if you know that $f$ is increasing, then this is allowable -- and $\sin$ is monotonic near $0$, so this is fine.